# How can i add GMSAutocompleteSessionToken to GMSAutocompleteViewController on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, google-places-autocomplete

I found the documentation not clear enough on how to add a sessionToken when instantiating a built-in autocomplete controller (GMSAutocompleteViewController).
Is this even needed / possible ?
Could GMSAutocompleteViewController be able to handle the request made smartly enough to match the behaviour of a custom autocomplete implementation with GMSAutocompleteSessionToken ?

Answer (score 0):

My bad I found the answer in the documentation

*Session tokens
Session tokens group the query and selection phases of a user autocomplete search into a discrete session for billing purposes. The session begins when the user starts typing a query, and concludes when they select a place. Each session can have multiple queries, followed by one place selection. Once a session has concluded, the token is no longer valid; your app must generate a fresh token for each session. We recommend using session tokens for all programmatic autocomplete sessions (when you use the full-screen controller, or the results controller, the API takes care of this automatically).*